# LeetCode 952: Largest Component Size by Common Factor

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem copied here. If you would like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

> Given a non-empty array of unique positive integers A, consider the
> following graph:
>
> - There are `nums.length` nodes, labeled `nums[0]` to `nums[nums.length - 1]`;
> - There is an edge between `nums[i]` and `nums[j]` if and only if `nums[i]` and `nums[j]` share a common factor greater than 1.
> - Return the size of the largest connected component in the graph.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> - Input: [4,6,15,35]
> - Output: 4
>
> [image]
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> - Input: [20,50,9,63]
> - Output: 2
>
> [image]
>
> #### Example 3:
>
> - Input: [2,3,6,7,4,12,21,39]
> - Output: 8
>
> [image]
>
> #### Note:
>
> - \$1 <= nums.length <= 20000\$
> - \$1 <= nums[i] <= 100000\$

#### Inputs

```
[4,6,15,35]
[20,50,9,63]
[2,3,6,7,4,12,21,39]
[2,3,6,7,4,12,21,39,100,101,102,103,104,1200,123,123,13424]
```

#### Outputs

```
4
2
8
15
```

#### Code

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cmath>

#define max(a, b) (a > b ? a : b) // std::max(a, b)

// Union Find
struct DisjointSets {
    DisjointSets(int_fast64_t n) : parent(n) {
        for (int_fast64_t index = 0; index < n; index++) {
            parent[index] = index;
        }
    }

    void union_ds(const int_fast64_t x, const int_fast64_t y) {
        parent[find_ds(x)] = parent[find_ds(y)];
    }

    const int_fast64_t find_ds(const int_fast64_t x) {
        if (parent[x] != x) {
            parent[x] = find_ds(parent[x]);
        }

        return parent[x];
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> parent;
};

struct Solution {
    static const size_t largestComponentSize(const std::vector<int> &nums) {
        const size_t max_nums = *std::max_element(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        DisjointSets union_find(max_nums + 1);

        for (const auto &num : nums) {
            for (size_t k = 2; k <= std::sqrt(num); k++) {
                if (num % k == 0) {
                    union_find.union_ds(num, k);
                    union_find.union_ds(num, num / k);
                }
            }
        }

        std::unordered_map<int, int> component_map;
        size_t largest_component = 1;

        for (const auto &num : nums) {
            size_t curr_component = ++component_map[union_find.find_ds(num)];
            largest_component = max(largest_component, curr_component);
        }

        return largest_component;
    }
};
```

#### References

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-component-size-by-common-factor/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-component-size-by-common-factor/discuss/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-component-size-by-common-factor/solution/)
- [Union Find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Observation

I don't understand your solution.

### Code Review

> ```
> #define max(a, b) (a > b ? a : b) // std::max(a, b)
> ```

Don't do this. Use `std::max()` directly.

Long gone are the days that we used macros to inline code like this. The `std::max()` will work correctly in all situations; this macro has edge cases that will fail (especially if `a` and `b` are not just simple numbers).

---

The `size_t` is coming because you included a C header file `cstdint`. It is not guaranteed to be in the global namespace (it commonly is but its not guaranteed). So prefer to use `std::size_t`.

```
        const std::size_t max_nums = *std::max_element(nums.begin(), nums.end());
```

Comment: Also, `std::int_fast64_t` is being assumed in global namespace; that's as non-portable is unqualified `size_t`.